# SWRevealViewController and UITabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController to create a Menu View. I am builded success and everything work fine like my Storyboard image below. Now what I want is when I push to Maps and Image ViewControllers(that 2 ViewControllers belong to MenuSide bard) my TabbarVC still display in that View I have to pushed. I try many ways and many things to find out but I think I need help.

Thank you.

[image: Storyboard!!]

Comment: Exctly what happen i didnt get you

Comment: @RushangPrajapati hi, all I want is when I choose any item in my MenuSlider it's will push to my view exactly and in that View my TabbarController like Tabbar in my Storyboard still display.

Comment: means u dont want to show tabbar on click on map?

Comment: I want show my tabbar when pushed to MapsViewController. Mean I want Tabbar display on MapsViewController.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use different flow for your Maps and Image view controllers.

So As I understood you right and as I see on image you've attached here is a **rear** view controller which include table view:

[image]

and **front** view controller which is `UINavigationController` and which includes `UITabBarViewController`:

[image]

So for example if you tap on some cell which display for you `UINavigationController` which includes `UITabBarViewController` there is only this flow that you will see in front view controller. As I see on your Storyboard you've put Image and Maps View controller in another flow.

So when you show up rear view and then tap on some menu cell `SWRevealViewController`toggles front view controller automatically with assigned flow.

It looks like you push or present Image or Maps view controller from rear view controller, but if you want to see tab bar you should work with **front** view controller flow which is in your case:

`UINavigationController` -> `UITabBarController` -> `UIViewcontrollers` array.

So you need then push or present view controllers from controllers which is part of your UITabBarViewController.

As I see your Image and Maps controllers are in another segue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I really don't understand what exactly you are explaining for me. If you have any example or demo about this case please help me out. Very thank you.

Comment: @sunsunai Hey) so let's talk about it step by step, do you know how rear view toogle front view?